# Get sub items in umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have the following structure:
[image: Umbraco Structure]

How do I access to Features of current Product in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any sample code? You would probably use the `Children` property. It would be something like

```
@foreach(var child in CurrentPage.Children)
{
    <span>@child.featureName @*Or whatever field you have on feature*@</span>
}
```

They put out a [cheat sheet](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-v6-mvc-razor-cheatsheets) which is always handy.

Comment: yes it worker. there is a Children property. thanks.